How can I properly bundle open source licenses?
I have made an open source app that is licensed under GNU GPL V3.0. I have dependencies that use the MIT, Apache 2.0 and CC-0 licenses. How can I properly include the license info in my app? Is it sufficient to have a section in the "about” page of my app that allows the user to view the licenses by opening them in another app?

Can you put the bit about the privacy policy in a question of its own? The Q&A format used here doesn't work well with having multiple questions in one post and the privacy policy question deserves the attention of its own Question.

@BartvanIngenSchenau I'm not convinced that a question about privacy policies would be on-topic here; it feels like a generic legal question, probably very dependent on the jurisdiction(s) involved.
